# Why is there no auto importing/loading of classes in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, autoload

like we have in php with composer?

`import {SomeThing} from "../../../some/stupid/path.class";`

is soo clumsy

Comment: ES Modules are all about explicit dependencies. While many find it irritating initially, it's actually a boon as it highlights complexity and interdependency.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a bit the exception there. Most programming languages do not have auto imports.

However, a good IDE will automatically add the imports for you. VsCode does it for JavaScript and TypeScript for example.